# Time Stamps..Only need 1st and last

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns date and time stamps for estimates. Each estimate can have multiple time stamps. I only need the first and last stamp. How can I accomplish this? My query looks like this:

```
SELECT LogDateTime, Operator, Program, Explanation, TransactionCode
FROM SystemLog
WHERE Program = 'Estimating'
ORDER BY TransactionCode
```

Comment: What is an estimate? Identified by TransactionCode?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `min()` and `max()` aggregate functions:

```
SELECT
    min(LogDateTime) as first_LogDateTime,
    max(LogDateTime) as last_LogDateTime,
    Operator, Program, Explanation, TransactionCode
FROM SystemLog
WHERE Program = 'Estimating'
GROUP BY Operator, Program, Explanation, TransactionCode
ORDER BY TransactionCode
```